# Download file from ASP.NET MVC 2 site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm currently trying to implement a controller where you can download files from (more specifically jar-archives). The files are stored on disk and not in database. So far I have come up with this:

```
public FilePathResult GetFile(String fileName) 
{    
   return File(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Bundles"), fileName), "application/java-archive");
}
```

Nevermind the lack of error handling and such at this time. The file do get downloaded this way, however it gets the wrong name. Instead of, for example, "sample.jar" the file gets the controller's name, "GetFile", (without extension).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `Content-Disposition` header tells the browser what filename to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the overload which allows you to specify the `fileDownloadName`.

```
return File(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Bundles"), fileName),
            "application/java-archive", 
            fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

If they are just stored on disk and you aren't doing anything other than just serving them why route them using the controller at all? You should just put them in `~/Content/Bundles` for example and link to them directly.

Then you don't have to worry about all the extra error/security handling on the `filename` parameter. Also typically it's a bad practice to serve files straight out of `App_Data` because generally this is the location for files that shouldn't be shared.

Comment: +1. Doesn't actually answer his question, but good to ask anyway!

Comment: @Craig-Stuntz Technically he asked "Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?" ;-)

Comment: Good point and also a correct answer. However, with time a request will be made with a id-nr instead of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The `File` has an overloaded version, I mean you have to add a 3rd argument with the file name.

```
return File(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Bundles"), fileName), 
       "application/java-archive", "putFileNamehere.extension");
```

Now, `putFileNamehere.extension` will be shown to the user in the File Download dialogue.